# Required Interface in component diagram on IBM RSA/Eclipse UML Plugin

Tags: eclipse, uml, rational-rsa

I have a interface. One component provide this interface, and another require this interface.
I can't represent it in IBM Rational Software Architect.

In the component that provide it (contains a class that is the interface realization), I added a port and selected the Class that realizes that interface.

In the component that requires it (contains the interface definition), I added a port and selected the Interface.

The result is correct, but there is a Class3 automatically created that I think is wrong.

[image]

So, I changed the Class3 to the Interface definition,and the RSA changes the required interface to provided interface.

How can I model this correct? I can't find on RSA docs.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the documentation.
I don't need to add Port.
I just need to drag and drop the interfaces in the component, choosing the provided or required area.